# My application always starts on the primary monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, visual-studio, start-screen, application-launch

I am running Visual Studio 2019 (Windows GUI application) on the 2nd monitor. When I build and start the application, it always appears on the primary/main monitor.

I want it to appear on the same monitor where I am running Visual Studio. I thought that if I drag the application to that monitor and close it, then it should start on that monitor the next time, but no, it still starts on the primary monitor.

How can I make it appear on the monitor I want it to?

Comment: What type of app (WPF/ASP/est.)?  Guessing WPF/C#.  Your app should always open up in the last location it was used (after checking if that location/monitor is still available.) The code below works, but it only a starting point - but gives you the tools you need to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging to a monitor and then closing window works for most of the applications. If not, then there are other ways to position your application window. Below are 2 of them,

**Method1: Move window programmatically**
`Screen.AllScreens` is an array which points to all active monitors. So  `Screen.AllScreens[0]` would be your primary monitor and `Screen.AllScreens[1]` would be second.
Now use below script to get handle to application window and then position it with help of 'SetWindowPos' method

```
// Get handle to active window
IntPtr windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

// get position for second monitor  
  secondMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;

// move application window to the second monitor
SetWindowPos(windowHandle, 0, secondMonitor.Left, secondMonitor.Top, secondMonitor.Width, secondMonitor.Height, 0);
```

**Method2: Move window manually through shortcut**
Simply allow apllication to open on primary monitor and then use shortcut `Windows`+`Shift`+`Left/Right Arrow` to move application between monitors.

You can explore other ways involving registry and third-party applications.